# gmaps4rails adding zoom controls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I'm using the latest gmaps4rails and I would like to add zoom controls to the map. I've had a look at the API and tried setting the raw options like so:

```
= gmaps({"map_options" => { :raw => "{scrollwheel: false, 
         disableDefaultUI: false, zoomControl: true, panControl: true, 
         zoomControlOptions: {style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE }}"},
         :markers => {:data => @json}})
```

This does not display any controls on the map though.

What do I have to do to display the map zoom controls?

Comment: Mmm, can't reproduce, any public url?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Gmaps.search_map.map_options.raw.zoomControl = true; // yes, raw
```

More options here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions